# How to change Font face and font size of OHAttributedLabel in iOS?

Tags: ios, uilabel, nsattributedstring

I used OHAttributedLabel and NSAttributedString+Attributes.h to have attributed label and I successfully achieved this. However I noticed that the font size and face isn't working. I changed the font form IB as well and from code using setFont:size of UILabel but no gain. I also searched over SO no no one is talking about this issue.

Edit: one more addition, is that possible to change line height for UILabel? I searched over SO and found some sample projects which allow altering row height but I'm already using OHAttributedLabel class so don't want to create mess of classes.

Kindly advice.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set Font and Size in NSAttributedString.

```
NSMutableAttributedString* attrStr = [NSMutableAttributedString attributedStringWithString:txt];
// Change font, text color, paragraph style
[attrStr setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:18]];
[attrStr setTextColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
```